Notepad with dark background and white font
I am using windows 10 with dark theme colors. My favorite applications, notepad, when high contrast setting is on becomes black with white font.
I would like my notepad to look like that, but without enabling this setting for everything else. Is it possible to edit registry to make black notepad in windows 10?

Hello, could you show a screenshot of what you mean? Regular Notepad app? And that's your favorite? Do you realize how outdated that is and how many better alternatives there are?

This is a question that has come up for many people in similar situations.
So lets adress the question itself first.
Can you modify settings to make Notepad use the inverse colorscheme, so it works in darkmode?
Unfortunately not.
There were a few people not satisfied with that answer, so there's now an alternative way.
From the Microsoft Store, you can download Black Notepad, an app that is exactly notepad, but customizable and with dark colorscheme in mind.
Here's what it looks like:

Do note, this was based on the Windows 10 version of Notepad, so it doesn't have the tab option that you find in the Windows 11 version. Also the text color can be set to either white or green. I show the green version as I like that one better.
Download from the Windows Store.
PS. There may be other apps that do a similar thing that may be more to your liking.
